# Neural Network Output Grouping 0.5?

Tags: neural-network

I tried to write a Neural Network system, but even running through simple AND/OR/NOR type problems, the outputs seem to group around 0.5 (for a bias of -1) and 0.7 (for a bias of 1).
It doesn't look exactly "wrong"... The 1,1 in the AND pattern does seem higher than the rest and the 0,0 in the OR looks lower, but they are still all grouped so it's debatable.

I was wondering a) if there's some obvious mistake I've made or b) if there's any advice for debugging Neural Nets... seeing as you can't always track back exactly where an answer came from...

Thanks!

Mike

Comment: This might be a little late to be asking but, I should be seeing much more of a range on my "outputs" right? It shouldn't be like... rounding 0.56 to 1 and 0.49 to 0? Everytime I check the individual formulas it's all coming through fine, so I think it's implementation rather than algorithm :) Which is more annoying :)

Comment: your sigmoid function is only responsible for normalizing the values and you should be rounding the values only if they're within your threshold of accuracy. Initially just try to produce a very small root mean square error, when that error falls below the threshold then and only then will you mark the instance as correctly classified.

Comment: I've been playing around with it a lot... I think the algorithms are right.
    DeltaWeightHiddenToOutput
    ( getLearningRate() * dHiddenValues[j] * dErrorGradients[1][i] ) + ( dWeightDelta[1][j][i] * getMomentum() );

    ErrorGradientForOutput = 
    inline double CalculateErrorGradient ( double dExpected, double dOutput ) { return dOutput * ( 1 - dOutput) * ( dExpected - dOutput ); }
    ErrorHiddenLayers
 for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < getOutputCount(); i++ )
  dWeighted += dWeightValues[1][x][i] * dErrorGradients[1][i];
 return dHiddenValues[x] * ( 1- dHiddenValues[x] ) * dWeighted;

Comment: It seems to work for lineraly separable problems... eventually... AND takes over 15000 epochs to learn... But for XOR it doesn't seem to be getting close...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered a similar question and I posted some values you can test against:

[Artificial neural networks benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359571/artificial-neural-networks-benchmark/2375593#2375593)

Use those values in order to test your neural network. Your outputs should match the values VERY closely, even if you're using different languages... you should be able match at least 6 digits after the decimal without a problem.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but woudldn't my weight values be different depending on things like... momentum (which I'm using 0.1) and that I'm using sigmoid as my activation wheras in your screenshot, sigmoid is deselected?

Comment: @Mike, Actually the screen shot is just to demonstrate the node architecture of the network... I specify the weights and values in the description and of course I use a sigmoid function. There should be no discrepancy between your results if you start out with the same weights and values in your nodes and you use backprop.

Answer (score 2):

for a) it's impossible to tell without more information.

for b) the best way I have found is to have a pre-calculated set of vectors and weights for a small test version of my network architecture and to have some debug code that dumps the network state out to a csv file so I can look at it in Excel.

The forward (and backward) passes of your network should be completely calculable manually for a single pattern, and a known network initial state, so it's a good idea to have a candidate pattern, or a couple if you can bear doing it manually, fully enumerated for your tests.  It's not actually as bad as it sounds.

Doing this has the added advantage that it reinforces your understanding of how the algorithm works and will cause you to check your implementation again from a different standpoint.

good luck.

P.S. shameless plug on backprop blog entry [here](http://simonpalmer.com/demystifying-backprop/)...