# Basic neural network returns the average of the target outputs

Tags: c, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm currently coding a basic neural network that is supposed to calculate a XOR, using backpropagation. However, it instead outputs the average of its target outputs. (A XOR returning {0,1,1,0}, that is 0.5).

I followed both the following articles [[1]](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2013/08/01/Neural-Network-Back-Propagation-Using-C.aspx?Page=2)[[2]](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16508/AI-Neural-Network-for-beginners-Part-of) and can't find my error. [That guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493554/neural-network-always-produces-same-similar-outputs-for-any-input) supposedly had the same problem, but never found an answer.

Anyway, here's my code:

`network.c`

```
void initialise_network(Network *network)
{
assert(network != NULL);
network->inputs[network->num_inputs] = 1.0;
network->hidden[network->num_hidden] = 1.0;

for (int i = 0; i < network->num_inputs+1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < network->num_hidden; j++)
    {
        network->ithw[i][j] = rnd_double(-1, 1);
        network->delta_hidden[i][j] = rnd_double(0, 0);
        printf("ithw[%d][%d]: %f\n", i, j, network->ithw[i][j]);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < network->num_hidden+1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < network->num_outputs; j++)
    {
        network->htow[i][j] = rnd_double(-1, 1);
        network->delta_output[i][j] = rnd_double(0, 0);
        // printf("htow[%d][%d]: %f\n", i, j, network->htow[i][j]);
    }
}
}

void pass_forward(double* inputs, Network *network)
{
log_info("pass_forward() !");
printf("Inputs: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < network->num_inputs; i++)
{
    network->inputs[i] = inputs[i];
    printf("%f, ", network->inputs[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < network->num_hidden; i++)
{
    double sum = 0.0;

    for (int j = 0; j < network->num_inputs+1; j++)
    {
        printf("\n inputs[%d]: %f", j, network->inputs[j]);
        sum += network->inputs[j] * network->ithw[j][i];
        printf("\nithw[%d][%d]: %f", j, i, network->ithw[j][i]);
        printf("\n sum[%d]: %f", j, sum);
    }
    printf("\n hidden[%d]: %f", i, sum);
    network->hidden[i] = sigmoid(sum);
    printf("\n sigmoid(hidden[%d]): %f", i, network->hidden[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < network->num_outputs; i++)
{
    double sum = 0.0;

    for (int j = 0; j < network->num_hidden+1; j++)
    {
        sum += network->hidden[j] * network->htow[j][i];
    }
    printf("\n output[%d]: %f\n", i, network->outputs[i]);
    network->outputs[i] = sigmoid(sum);
}
}
```

`trainer_xor.c`

```
void train_network(double *target_output, Network *network)
{
double *delta_hidden = malloc(sizeof(double) * network->num_hidden + 1);
double *delta_output = malloc(sizeof(double) * network->num_outputs);

double momentum = 0.1;

printf("Inputs: %f, %f\n", network->inputs[0], network->inputs[1]);
printf("Output: %f\n", network->outputs[0]);
printf("Target Output: %f\n", target_output[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < network->num_outputs; i++)
{
    delta_output[i] = network->outputs[i] * (1.0 - network->outputs[i]) *
        (target_output[i] - network->outputs[i]);
    printf("delta_output: %f\n", delta_output[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < network->num_hidden + 1; i++)
{
    double error = 0.0;

    for (int j = 0; j < network->num_outputs; j++)
    {
        error += network->htow[i][j] * delta_output[j];
    }

    delta_hidden[i] = network->hidden[i] * (1.0 - network->hidden[i]) * error;

    printf("hidden[%d]: %f\n", i, network->hidden[i]);
    printf("delta_hidden[%d]: %f\n", i, delta_hidden[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < network->num_outputs; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < network->num_hidden + 1; j++)
    {
        double delta = network->learning_rate * delta_output[i] * network->hidden[j];
        network->htow[j][i] += delta;
        network->htow[j][i] += momentum * network->delta_output[j][i];
        network->delta_output[j][i] = delta;
        // printf("htow[%d][%d]: %f\n", i, j, network->htow[i][j]);
        printf("htow[%d][%d]: %f\n", j, i, network->htow[j][i]);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < network->num_hidden; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < network->num_inputs + 1; j++)
    {
        double delta = network->learning_rate * delta_hidden[i] * network->inputs[j];
        network->ithw[j][i] += delta;
        network->ithw[j][i] += momentum * network->delta_hidden[j][i];
        network->delta_hidden[j][i] = delta;
        printf("ithw[%d][%d]: %f\n", j, i, network->ithw[j][i]);
    }
}

getchar();
}

void do_training(int training_times, Trainer *trainer)
{
trainer->training_times = training_times;

for (int i = 0; i < training_times; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < trainer->train_set_size; j++)
    {
        pass_forward(trainer->train_set[j], trainer->network);
        train_network(get_target_values(trainer->train_set[j], trainer->train_set_size),
            trainer->network);
    }
}
}
```

`main.c`

```
int main() 
{
initialize_utils();
Network *network = network_create(2, 2, 1);
initialise_network(network);
Trainer *trainer = trainer_create(network);
do_training(300, trainer);
return 0;
}
```

I train my network for 300 times. The train_set is as follows:

```
[0][0] = 0
[0][1] = 0

[1][0] = 1
[1][1] = 0

[2][0] = 0
[2][1] = 1

[3][0] = 1
[3][1] = 1
```

For more informations, here are my outputs at a certain time:

Gen 0:

```
=== Gen 0! ===
[INFO] (src/network.c:100) pass_forward() !
Inputs: 
0.000000, 0.000000, 
inputs[0]: 0.000000
ithw[0][0]: 0.316492
sum[0]: 0.000000
inputs[1]: 0.000000
ithw[1][0]: -0.028962
sum[1]: 0.000000
inputs[2]: 1.000000
ithw[2][0]: -0.915344
sum[2]: -0.915344
hidden[0]: -0.915344
sigmoid(hidden[0]): 0.285908
inputs[0]: 0.000000
ithw[0][1]: 0.089068
sum[0]: 0.000000
inputs[1]: 0.000000
ithw[1][1]: 0.176854
sum[1]: 0.000000
inputs[2]: 1.000000
ithw[2][1]: 0.958716
sum[2]: 0.958716
hidden[1]: 0.958716
sigmoid(hidden[1]): 0.722865
output[0]: 0.000000
train_network()!
Inputs: 0.000000, 0.000000
Output: 0.625586
Target Output: 0.000000
delta_output: -0.146530
hidden[0]: 0.285908
delta_hidden[0]: 0.002849
hidden[1]: 0.722865
delta_hidden[1]: 0.007222
hidden[2]: 1.000000
delta_hidden[2]: -0.000000
htow[0][0]: -0.107817
htow[1][0]: -0.277817
htow[2][0]: 0.674453
ithw[0][0]: 0.316492
ithw[1][0]: -0.028962
ithw[2][0]: -0.914489
ithw[0][1]: 0.089068
ithw[1][1]: 0.176854
ithw[2][1]: 0.960883
```

Gen 1:

```
=== Gen 1! ===
[INFO] (src/network.c:100) pass_forward() !
Inputs: 
0.000000, 0.000000, 
 inputs[0]: 0.000000
ithw[0][0]: 0.316628
 sum[0]: 0.000000
 inputs[1]: 0.000000
ithw[1][0]: -0.028659
 sum[1]: 0.000000
 inputs[2]: 1.000000
ithw[2][0]: -0.914866
 sum[2]: -0.914866
 hidden[0]: -0.914866
 sigmoid(hidden[0]): 0.286005
 inputs[0]: 0.000000
ithw[0][1]: 0.089247
 sum[0]: 0.000000
 inputs[1]: 0.000000
ithw[1][1]: 0.177256
 sum[1]: 0.000000
 inputs[2]: 1.000000
ithw[2][1]: 0.959846
 sum[2]: 0.959846
 hidden[1]: 0.959846
 sigmoid(hidden[1]): 0.723091
 output[0]: 0.625643
train_network()
Inputs: 0.000000, 0.000000
Output: 0.613576
Target Output: 0.000000
delta_output: -0.145479
hidden[0]: 0.286005
delta_hidden[0]: 0.003118
hidden[1]: 0.723091
delta_hidden[1]: 0.007844
hidden[2]: 1.000000
delta_hidden[2]: -0.000000
htow[0][0]: -0.118963
htow[1][0]: -0.304226
htow[2][0]: 0.639053
ithw[0][0]: 0.316718
ithw[1][0]: -0.028568
ithw[2][0]: -0.913841
ithw[0][1]: 0.089431
ithw[1][1]: 0.177440
ithw[2][1]: 0.962383
```

Gen 10:

```
=== Gen 10! ===
[INFO] (src/network.c:100) pass_forward() !
Inputs: 
0.000000, 0.000000, 
 inputs[0]: 0.000000
ithw[0][0]: 0.317382
 sum[0]: 0.000000
 inputs[1]: 0.000000
ithw[1][0]: -0.025525
 sum[1]: 0.000000
 inputs[2]: 1.000000
ithw[2][0]: -0.911555
 sum[2]: -0.911555
 hidden[0]: -0.911555
 sigmoid(hidden[0]): 0.286682
 inputs[0]: 0.000000
ithw[0][1]: 0.089229
 sum[0]: 0.000000
 inputs[1]: 0.000000
ithw[1][1]: 0.180321
 sum[1]: 0.000000
 inputs[2]: 1.000000
ithw[2][1]: 0.967483
 sum[2]: 0.967483
 hidden[1]: 0.967483
 sigmoid(hidden[1]): 0.724618
 output[0]: 0.547804
Inputs: 0.000000, 0.000000
Output: 0.539370
Target Output: 0.000000
delta_output: -0.134006
hidden[0]: 0.286682
delta_hidden[0]: 0.004474
hidden[1]: 0.724618
delta_hidden[1]: 0.010913
hidden[2]: 1.000000
delta_hidden[2]: -0.000000
htow[0][0]: -0.176218
htow[1][0]: -0.440373
htow[2][0]: 0.456051
ithw[0][0]: 0.317521
ithw[1][0]: -0.025386
ithw[2][0]: -0.910074
ithw[0][1]: 0.089499
ithw[1][1]: 0.180592
ithw[2][1]: 0.971027
```

Gen 100:

```
=== Gen 100! ===
[INFO] (src/network.c:100) pass_forward() !
Inputs: 
0.000000, 0.000000, 
 inputs[0]: 0.000000
ithw[0][0]: 0.295665
 sum[0]: 0.000000
 inputs[1]: 0.000000
ithw[1][0]: -0.014208
 sum[1]: 0.000000
 inputs[2]: 1.000000
ithw[2][0]: -0.929113
 sum[2]: -0.929113
 hidden[0]: -0.929113
 sigmoid(hidden[0]): 0.283105
 inputs[0]: 0.000000
ithw[0][1]: 0.023758
 sum[0]: 0.000000
 inputs[1]: 0.000000
ithw[1][1]: 0.161541
 sum[1]: 0.000000
 inputs[2]: 1.000000
ithw[2][1]: 0.932629
 sum[2]: 0.932629
 hidden[1]: 0.932629
 sigmoid(hidden[1]): 0.717608
 output[0]: 0.512934
Inputs: 0.000000, 0.000000
Output: 0.505055
Target Output: 0.000000
delta_output: -0.126251
hidden[0]: 0.283105
delta_hidden[0]: 0.004697
hidden[1]: 0.717608
delta_hidden[1]: 0.011935
hidden[2]: 1.000000
delta_hidden[2]: -0.000000
htow[0][0]: -0.195365
htow[1][0]: -0.496565
htow[2][0]: 0.365162
ithw[0][0]: 0.295813
ithw[1][0]: -0.014059
ithw[2][0]: -0.927556
ithw[0][1]: 0.024074
ithw[1][1]: 0.161856
ithw[2][1]: 0.936526
```

Comment: I've seen this happen before with an XOR network, and it was due to the learning algorithm (not your implementation of it, just SGD in general has a hard time learning this problem). You might try creating a larger dataset by adding small amounts of noise to the inputs, and see whether that helps.

Comment: I should state that it has happened to me with an And as well. I'll still try, though. Also, by bit of noise, you suggest adding inputs like 0.9 and 0.8 ?

Comment: If that was what you meant, it didn't change anything, excepted the average being slightly higher.

Answer (score 0):

Kino, do you know that you need to train the network in multiple backpropagation passes until it converges, that is, until the weights change so that the difference between your target outputs and the actual outputs becomes smaller than some tolerance?

train_network() only seems to make one pass, are you doing the rest of the training elsewhere?

Something like:

```
const double TOLERANCE = 0.001;
while( fabs(network->outputs[ 0 ] - target_output[ 0 ]) > TOLERANCE &&
    fabs(network->outputs[ 1 ] - target_output[ 1 ]) > TOLERANCE ) {

    train_network(target_output, network);
}
```

(But it's probably neater to do the loop in train_network() itself.)

Comment: I do, but didn't paste the function. I'll edit my post.

Comment: OK.  What are your 'training_times' and training sets?  I'm wondering if your weights could be oscillating.  Maybe post your main() function and the output from your printf() calls?

Comment: Added information. I only posted information of when the input was 0,0, but it does train for all the inputs.